# Comprobar si valores de una tabla han sido modificados

Tags: php, jquery, html5

Tengo una tabla con campos modificables que se alimenta de una consulta a una base de datos. El usuario tiene posibilidad de modificar los valores, añadir o eliminar líneas. Necesito comprobar si un valor de esa tabla ha sido modificado para marcarlo y que el servidor se encargue de modificar el valor.

¿Como puedo comprobar los valores iniciales con los actuales para gestionar que ha sido modificado y que no?

Comment: En estos casos, lo usual es hacer los cambios al mismo tiempo que el usuario.  Por ejemplo, si editas o eliminas una linea, despues que el usuario confirma, mandar la informacion al servidor.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Sería bueno que colocaras un código de ejemplo en el que podamos depurar para entender mejor el problema. Un saludo!